# What is the difference between .app and .app.src files in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I found these description in the Erlang doc and learnyousomeerlang.com, but not sure which one is the "Application Resource File". When should I use .app and .app.src?

7.3 Application Resource File
http://www.erlang.org/doc/design_principles/applications.html

The Application Resource File
http://learnyousomeerlang.com/building-otp-applications

Comment: `src/_.app.src` is used by building tools like rebar to generate `ebin/_.app` file. I believe the most useful part of generation process is filling [`modules`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/app.html) list that contains list of all modules introduced by this application, so it's very useful in development process.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `.app` file (in `ebin/`) is the file necessary by the Erlang VM to load OTP applications. It must contain fields such as the dependencies of the application, the modules it contains, the version, and so on.

Particularly, the list of modules for the application is tedious to maintain, but there's other stuff that can be dynamically added. People write `.app.src` files (in `src/`) with the static content filled in so that their build tool of choice (rebar, rebar3, erlang.mk, and so on) can fill in the dynamic parts with what they want, such as the modules found on disk.

This allows for a more streamlined dev process with a lot less stuff to juggle and maintain by hand.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding is that the OTP application should have the *application.app* file in the *ebin* directory together with the compiled beam-files.

Keeping an *application.app.src* file (which would be identical to the one in the *ebin* directory) in the *src* directory is optional but can be useful to have the build process generate the *application.app* file.